# Blurry translucent effect of UINavigationBar/UIVisualEffectView while scrolling on a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, wkwebview, uivisualeffectview

I'd like to achieve the same effect as in Safari where the navigation bar changes slightly in color to reflect the web page that passes through while scrolling.

[image]

The 6 years old method that used to work with **UIWebView** is to simply include these two lines of code:

```
webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    
webView.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = _webView.scrollView.contentInset;
```

Since **WKWebView** the edge insets work much like content offset. It displays correctly initially but when you scroll the web page moves underneath the UINavigationBar/UIVisualEffectView making in it impossible to reach the top bar of websites that adjust accordingly, like at apple.com

Is there any other way?

***The answers below are 6 years old and obsolete.***

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the web view under the navigation bar, and then set the web view's `contentInset`, like so:

```
navBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44);
webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0);
webView.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = webView.scrollView.contentInset;
```

Comment: I only change: UIEdgeInsetsMake(-44, 0, 0, 0);

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to you app setting in xcode and in Status Bar Style click the drop down and select "Light".
These should apply in all your app